# Добавление метаданных пользователю при регистрации с помощью хука "user_register"

Tags: wordpress

Почему не добавляются метаданные пользователю при регистрации? Я сделал шаблон в папке с темой для регистрации пользователя. Вот код.

```
<form method = "post" action="http://www.example.com/sample-page/">
<div class="main">
    <small>Логин и имя</small>
    <br>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="login"><small>Логин *</small></label>
        <input required align="right" name="login" type="text" maxlength="50">
    </div>
    <br>
        <small>Email</small>
    <br>
    <div class="field">
        <label for"mail"><small>Электронная почта *</small></label>
        <input required align="right" name="mail" type="text" maxlength="70">
    </div>
    <br>
        <small>Пароль</small>
    <br>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="password"><small>Пароль *</small></label>
        <input required align="right" name="password" type="password" maxlength="70">
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="user_phone"><small>Номер телефона *</small></label>
        <input required type="text" name="user_phone">
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<button>                        
    Сохранить
</button>
<?php
    $user_login = isset( $_POST['login'] ) ? $_POST['login'] : '';
    $user_email = isset( $_POST['mail'] ) ? $_POST['mail'] : '';
    $user_pass  = isset( $_POST['password'] ) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
    $user_phone  = isset( $_POST['user_phone'] ) ? $_POST['user_phone'] : '';

    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_login, $user_pass, $user_email );
        // предварительная проверка поля
    add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'my_validate_user_data' );
    function my_validate_user_data( $errors ){
        if( empty($_POST['user_phone']) )
        $errors->add('empty_user_phone', 'Телефон обязательно должен быть указан!' );
        return $errors;
    }
        // обновление метаданных пользователя
    add_action( 'user_register', 'my_user_registration' );
    function my_user_registration( $user_id ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_phone', $user_phone);
    }                       

    if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
        echo '<br><small>'.$user_id->get_error_message();                                    
    }else {
        echo '<br><small>'.'Пользователь зарегистрирован.';
    }                                 
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фильтры и действия надо добавлять до их использования. У вас же на момент вызова `wp_create_user()` WordPress ничего о них не знает.

Такой порядок должен быть в коде:

```
// предварительная проверка поля
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'my_validate_user_data' );
    // обновление метаданных пользователя
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_user_registration' );
$user_id = wp_create_user( $user_login, $user_pass, $user_email );
```