# При использовании хука "user_register" добавляется строка в таблицу "wp_usermeta", но не добавляется значение строки через форму $_POST

Tags: wordpress

Я сделал шаблон с пользовательской регистрацией. Все сделал так, как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/893194/297355) написано. Вот код, как я сделал.

```
<form method = "post" action="http://www.example.com/sample-page/">
<div class="main">
    <small>Логин и имя</small>
    <br>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="login"><small>Логин *</small></label>
        <input required align="right" name="login" type="text" maxlength="50">
    </div>
    <br>
        <small>Email</small>
    <br>
    <div class="field">
        <label for"mail"><small>Электронная почта *</small></label>
        <input required align="right" name="mail" type="text" maxlength="70">
    </div>
    <br>
        <small>Пароль</small>
    <br>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="password"><small>Пароль *</small></label>
        <input required align="right" name="password" type="password" maxlength="70">
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="user_phone"><small>Номер телефона *</small></label>
        <input required type="text" name="user_phone">
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<button>                        
    Сохранить
</button>
<?php
    $user_login = isset( $_POST['login'] ) ? $_POST['login'] : '';
    $user_email = isset( $_POST['mail'] ) ? $_POST['mail'] : '';
    $user_pass  = isset( $_POST['password'] ) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
    $user_phone  = isset( $_POST['user_phone'] ) ? $_POST['user_phone'] : '';

        // предварительная проверка поля
    add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'my_validate_user_data' );
    function my_validate_user_data( $errors ){
        if( empty($_POST['user_phone']) )
        $errors->add('empty_user_phone', 'Телефон обязательно должен быть указан!' );
        return $errors;
    }
        // обновление метаданных пользователя
    add_action( 'user_register', 'my_user_registration' );
    function my_user_registration( $user_id ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_phone', $user_phone);
    }

    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_login, $user_pass, $user_email );                       

    if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
        echo '<br><small>'.$user_id->get_error_message();                                    
    }else {
        echo '<br><small>'.'Пользователь зарегистрирован.';
    }                                 
?>
</form>
```

После этого в таблице "wp_usermeta" стала добавляться строка "user_phone" новому пользователю, но значение этой строки = "null". [image: Значение строки "user_phone"(Префикс таблиц "ssl_"))] Пробовал сделать без этого:

```
$user_phone  = isset( $_POST['user_phone'] ) ? $_POST['user_phone'] : '';
```

Вот так:

```
$user_phone = $_POST[user_phone];
```

Все равно данные не добавлялись в строку. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в фукции `my_user_registration` локальная переменная `$user_phone` не определена. Естественно, что её значение null, которое и записывается в базу. Почитайте про области видимости переменных в php.

Код можно исправить таким образом:

```
function my_user_registration( $user_id ) {
    $user_phone  = isset( $_POST['user_phone'] ) ? $_POST['user_phone'] : '';
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_phone', $user_phone);
}
```

А вообще, начните использовать современный инструментарий при создании кода - IDE типа PhpStorm, и тогда у вас не будет подобных ошибок. IDE вам сразу покажет, что `$user_phone` не определена в вашем коде.

Comment: Супер, спасибо, все работает. Я изменяю шаблон на хостинге в каком-то своем редакторе, там есть только подсветка синтаксиса. Сейчас попробую через FileZilla изменять прямо в IDE, спасибо за совет.

Comment: не надо через FileZilla. IDE имеют встроенные средства sftp/ssh